# Should we tag "best-of" lists with "best-of"?

Tags: discussion, tags

I think that these subjective list questions are useful, so it would be nice to have a separate tag for them (as in this example: [What is the best introductory Bayesian statistics textbook?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/125/what-is-the-best-introductory-bayesian-statistics-textbook)).

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't think there should be a best-of tag.

The question that you are describing will always be a community wiki question. The tag will not give any more information about the real content of the question, but instead be used to indicate the type of question. Because community wiki is already doing this (kind of) I think it is completely unnecessary.

Comment: IMO, the point of the tag is to group similar questions together and help with searching.

Comment: @Shane Searching on community wiki questions is already possible. I think tags should be used to group questions about similar topics, not to group them about different question formats/types.

Comment: Community wiki just means "does not have a definitive answer" in my view.  There could be many reasons besides these lists to mark something as community wiki.  So I don't see how that would help with searching...

Comment: @Shane Can you give an example of 1) a question that is community wiki but not a sum-up list, and 2) a real search query you would like to perform (and why)

Comment: Peter, my impression is that a CW was, at best, vaguely/broadly defined so the community could decide when something wasn't a "question" and nudge it in the CW direction or close it.  (And this is after going back to look at meta-SO.)  Hence so many discussions and accusations of CW police, etc.  Your question (1) seems to take the opposite tack and define it pretty *narrowly* ("a sum-up list") and ask for a counter-example.  Not fair!  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a separate tag would be helpful. However, instead of "best-of" what about "list of"? This is because some of the lists, e.g. [my blog question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/114/what-statistical-blogs-would-you-recommend), aren't really 'best of', they are just lists.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  It's only after consulting last year's list do I figure out what to wear this year.  This tag thing will make the entire process much smoother.

(No, seriously, that's a Yes vote.)